# Minimize System of Equations with constraints (scipy.optimize.minimize)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, minimize

Consider the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def eq( p ):
    s1,s2,s3 = p 
    f1 = 1.1**3 / s1*1.1**1+s2*1.1**2+s3*1.1**3
    f2 = 0.9**1 / s1*0.9**1+s2*0.9**2+s3*0.9**3
    return (f1, f2) 

bnds = ( (0, None), (0, None), (0, None) )
cons = ( { 'type' : 'ineq', 'fun': lambda p: p[0]+p[1]+p[2] - 1} )


minimize( eq, (0.3,0.3,0.3),  bounds=bnds, constraints=cons )
```

throws the error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'tuple'
```

I want to minimize `f1` and `f2` such that the `s_t > 0` and `sum s_t <= 1`, for t = 1, 2, 3.

Comment: `p[0]+[p1]+[p2]` This is wrong, isn't it?

Comment: This should model the constraint that `sum s_t <= 1`. I also notices that I need to specify `method='SLSQP'` to allow constraints, but then it fails with `error: failed in converting 8th argument g' of _slsqp.slsqp to C/Fortran array` - I saw this error in another topic here on stackoverflow, but without an answer ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
minimize( eq, (0.3,0.3,0.3),  bounds=bnds, constraints=cons )
```

The second argument should be an ndarray not a tuple.  The args tuple comes after the initial guess (x0).

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter should be of type ndarray, try using

```
 minimize( eq, np.ndarray([0.3,0.3,0.3]),  bounds=bnds, constraints=cons )
```