# Solving for a set of nonlinear equations that produces an output with minimum variance

Tags: python, optimization, svm, libsvm

I have a set of features A, B, C and want to predict the number of events I'll see given a combination of these features.  I'm planning to use svm regression to generate a set of nonlinear equations to model different event occurrences.

So at the end of the day, I'll have several dozen nonlinear equations that model event outcome.

```
e.g. 
eventA_count = 3A^2 -5 B^2 + 3C^3 + intercept
eventB_count = 3A^2 -2B^2 + C^4 + intercept  
etc...
```

I want to create a set of A, B and C values that are constrained to the values [0,1] and produces minimum variance between all of my eventA_count, eventB_count etc.. but does not just set them to the value 0.

What would be the best way to solve for this?  My main confusion is how to use tools like scypy.optimize or solve when I don't have an actual number for the answer to all of my equations i.e. eventA_count is a var instead of a const like 5.

Since I want to minimize variance, I thought a potential way to guarantee this is to solve for the variance equation of all event counts and set it to 0. This is unrealistic since however, since I can't achieve 0 variance, rather I'm only looking for minimum variance.

Please let me know where I need to clarify or if I need to put in my current code.

Comment: Have you looked at scipy.optimize.minimize?

Comment: I thought minimize only worked for one equation not a set of equations

Comment: Looks like it can be applied to a SOE, will update this post if it works or doesn't : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36108921/minimize-system-of-equations-with-constraints-scipy-optimize-minimize